# NestJs monorepo with independently versioned artefacts

Tags: typescript, nestjs, monorepo

NestJs tooling [supports monorepos](https://docs.nestjs.com/cli/monorepo) and it works ok, but it uses a single `package.json` on the root level, for the whole set of projects. I haven't found support for the following two related questions:

- how can I build only the *subprojects* that have changed since the last release (or from the base of my current branch)?
- how can I version *subprojects* independently from the other ones?